# python: flake8 cannot find non exising method

Tags: python, flake8

If I do something like:

```
new_list = []
new_list.foo()
```

flake8 does not return an error for foo() method since it is not a 'list' method.

Is this normal or do I need to configure something?

Comment: You're asking for static analysis, which is very hard in a dynamic language, and certainly out of scope for what pylint does.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`flake8` does not handle the problem, but [`PyLint`](https://docs.pylint.org/) does - issues the `no-member` warning:

```
$ pylint test.py
No config file found, using default configuration
************* Module test
C:  1, 0: Missing module docstring (missing-docstring)
C:  1, 0: Invalid constant name "new_list" (invalid-name)
E:  2, 0: Instance of 'list' has no 'foo' member (no-member)
```

And, the [built-in to PyCharm code analyzer](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/2016.1/code-inspection.html) would also warn about the unresolved attribute:

[image]

Comment: I am using emacs and after reading your comment I set it up to use pylint as well and now I am getting the error. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

> [Flake8](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/flake8) is a wrapper around these tools:
>
> - PyFlakes
> - pep8
> - Ned Batchelder’s McCabe script

[PyFlakes](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyflakes) is the part that you might expect to detect this type of error. But it detects very little, and it explains why:

> Pyflakes is also faster than Pylint or Pychecker. This is largely because Pyflakes only examines the syntax tree of each file individually. As a consequence, Pyflakes is more limited in the types of things it can check.

The [flake8](http://flake8.readthedocs.io/en/latest/warnings.html) docs list the error codes provided by Pyflakes:

```
code    sample message
F401    module imported but unused
F402    import module from line N shadowed by loop variable
F403    ‘from module import *’ used; unable to detect undefined names
F404    future import(s) name after other statements
F811    redefinition of unused name from line N
F812    list comprehension redefines name from line N
F821    undefined name name
F822    undefined name name in __all__
F823    local variable name ... referenced before assignment
F831    duplicate argument name in function definition
F841    local variable name is assigned to but never used
```

I second the recommendation for PyCharm, followed by PyLint.